# Which class does LongAdder extends?

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8

While referring JavaDocs for LongAdder, it's extending **Number** class.

[image: Java docs LongAdder]

Then while looking at source code , It's extending from **Striped64**

[image: LongAdder source code]

It's quite confusing for me, Why we can't specify in javadocs that *LongAdder extending from Striped64 class* ?
Is it because **Striped64** extends **Number** ?

Comment: Because `Striped64` is not public API whereas `Number` is.

Comment: An important additional consideration is that, since Striped64 is not public, a future version of Java SE is free to change this hierarchy:  LongAdder might extend a totally different class, or extend Number directly.  Therefore, any code outside of the java.util.concurrent.atomic package that relies on the existence of Striped64 in any way is broken code.

Answer (score 5):

> Which class does LongAdder extends?

As shown in the source, it extends `Striped64`. Since that class is not public API, however, the Javadoc doesn't tell you that.

---

Javadoc, by default, only generates documentation for `public` and `protected` members; in other words, only the public API is documented<sup>1</sup>. The `Striped64` class is package-private and is thus not documented. Since the class is not documented the next closest documented ancestor is found, which happens to be `Number` in this case. Note you could have a documented class `Foo` that has 15+ ancestors, but if none of those ancestors are public API the Javadoc will show `Foo extends Object`.

From the perspective of public API versus private API, the fact `LongAdder` extends `Striped64` is irrelevant. The latter class is an *implementation detail* (i.e. private API). It's the public API that defines the contracts of a library; hence a user only cares that `LongAdder` is a subclass of `Number` in this case.

You can configure Javadoc to document everything, including package-private and `private` members, if needed. However, the generated documentation should probably only be for private use (e.g. internal to the organization maintaining the library).

---

<sup>1. What makes an API public or private is not solely based on the visibility modifier. What package the class is in is also relevant. For instance, the JDK has many classes in packages with prefixes such as `com.sun`, `oracle`, `jdk.internal`, and so on. The classes in those packages are private API and are thus not documented in the publicly available Javadoc.</sup>

<sup>The idea of "private packages" obtained more official status in Java 9 with the advent of modules. Now you can explicitly declare which packages are exported by a module and this is enforced by the runtime.</sup>

Comment: 1+; that `Striped64` is _so_ good, that guava and some other projects had to copy it in their library code.

Comment: Similarly, `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` are shown as extending `Object`, hiding their common, non-public base class `AbstractStringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

**They may be extending** `Number` **class in** `LongAdder`, **who knows ?**

> From Oracle Docs :

- **[AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html)**

[image]

- **[LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html)**

[image]

**It can be concluded that** `LongAdder` **uses** `AtomicLong` **by extending** `Striped64`.

**Q : Why Striped64 is extended by LongAdder ?**

> A : `Striped64` holds a hash table of Cells (where each Cell is a variant of
>   `AtomicLong`). When multiple threads are used to add values to a
>   `LongAdder` (which extends `Striped64`), then the threads add their values
>   to different cells in that hash table. This leads to concurrent thread
>   processing and increases the throughput.

**May be Striped64 is an internal implementation rather and they wanted it to be abstracted.**