# javadoc generate "extends Object" instead of the real class when the parent class is package private and comes from another module

Tags: java, javadoc, package-private

My file structure. I have 2 directories next to each other. module1 and module2.

***module1:***

src\hu\package1\TestPackagePrivateClass.java:

```
package hu.package1;

abstract class TestPackagePrivateClass { }
```

src\hu\package1\PackagePrivateClass2.java:

```
package hu.package1;

abstract class PackagePrivateClass2 { }
```

src\hu\package1\TestPublicClass.java:

```
package hu.package1;

public abstract class TestPublicClass { }
```

So 2 abstract package-private classes and 1 pubic abstract class.

***module2:***

src\hu\package1\TestChildClass.java:

```
package hu.package1;

public abstract class TestChildClass extends TestPackagePrivateClass {

    public PackagePrivateClass2 getPackagePrivateClass2() { return null; }

    public TestPublicClass getTestPublicClass() { return null; }

}
```

src\hu\package1\TestChildClass2.java:

```
package hu.package1;

public abstract class TestChildClass2 extends TestPublicClass {
}
```

src\hu\package2\ThirdChildClass.java:

```
package hu.package2;

import hu.package1.TestChildClass;

public class ThirdChildClass extends TestChildClass { }
```

So I run the following 2 commands... The first 2 from module1 and the second 2 from module2:

```
javac.exe -d .\build -target 1.8 src\hu\package1\*.java

javadoc.exe hu.package1 -sourcepath .\src -d .\doc -private

javac.exe -d .\build -target 1.8 -cp ..\module1\build src\hu\package1\*.java src\hu\package2\*.java

javadoc.exe hu.package1 hu.package2 -sourcepath .\src -cp ..\module1\build -d .\doc -private -link ..\..\module1\doc
```

Everything works perfectly fine, no warnings, no errors.

However my problem is that in the generated javadoc for module2 specifically for TestChildClass it shows that it extends from Object, and not from TestPackagePrivateClass. However the return type of getPackagePrivateClass2 is perfectly shown. Note that for TestChildClass2 which extends TestPublicClass from module1, the parent class is sown correct.

**So it seems that javadoc is not displaying the parent class when it comes from another module and its not public.** Is there a solution for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: [Which class does LongAdder extends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945073/which-class-does-longadder-extends)

Comment: You would have to configure Javadoc to document package-private members; by default it only documents public and protected members. Note, however, that exposing a package-private class as the return type of a public or protected method doesn't make sense—external users of the method wouldn't have access to the class.

Comment: I know that package-private return type there doesn't make sense, that was only for testing purposes. About the configuration you mentioned. As you can see in my commands above, I added the -private switch. What's that good for if not for properly documenting my stuff?

Comment: It's possible that Javadoc doesn't handle split packages well (if you were to use Java 9 modules I don't believe your code would even compile). What happens if you try to generate the Javadoc with both modules on the source path?